Number of attempts
Dislpaying a number of times something was done forces us to use for example present perfect simple and not continuous. 1 version right 2 wrong.


I have played 5 times this week.

I have been playing 5 times this week.



Does it apply to every continuous tense and continuous form? Let's me give some examples:


I should be playing 3 times this morning.

I should play 3 times this morning.

I'm supposed to be playing 3 times this morning.

I'm supposed to play 3 times this morning.



Are 3 and 4 correct or no because I state the exact number of attempts?

@Kate Bunting. I changed 3 and 4. Are they correct? DoI need to use the simple version because of specifying the number of attempts?

They are valid sentences. (3) means that it's possible that I will have two opportunities to play a game or musical instrument this afternoon. I don't know what you mean by 'the simple version'.

@Kate Bunting. We say " I have played 5 times this week" not " I have been playing 5 times this week". That's why I think that I need to say "I could play 2 times this afternoon" instead of "I could be playing 2 times this afternoon". What do you think? I mean only one afternoon not something repeated every afternoon.

It's confusing for a learner, I know, but it is idiomatic to use the continuous tense when speaking of something that you may have the opportunity to do in the future.

@ Kate Bunting. Even if I provide the exact number of attempts? For instance  "she's certain to be calling you at least 4 times this afternoon. She's really stubborn."

I said "something that you may have the opportunity to do", not "something that someone else is likely to do". Also, it's only an 'attempt' of it isn't successful. But I think you could use the continuous tense in that example, because it gives the idea of 'constantly trying to speak to you on the phone'.

You can use the past continuous tense, if expressing frequency, e.g.,

I've been taking aspirin two times [or twice] a day.
She has been practicing piano twice a week.

The same applies to the present and future continuous; all of these are acceptable:

I'm playing two times this week.

I will be playing two times this week.

I could be playing two times this afternoon.

She's likely to be calling two times this afternoon.


[Note some corrections:

Sentences begin with CAPITAL letters.
Sentences require end punctuation, e.g., full stop (period), question mark, and exclamation  point.
In formal English, it is suggested one writes numbers zero through nine.]


I don't think you understand me. I don't mean things repeated every day or week. I mean that something happend only during one day or week it wasn't repeated every week. Are then my examples relates to future correct?

No, continuous tenses imply continuing action. If I too aspiring twice yesterday, and not previously, I would state, "I had taken aspirin twice, yesterday."

"She's likely to be calling two times this afternoon"   Why not two times every afternoon? This sentce with "two times this afternoon" implies only one afternoon thus it's wrong the simple version should have been used. What's your opinion?

Sure, "She's likely to be calling every day." Insert any number of times you wish, e.g., "twice every day," or thrice a day.

Putting aside the twice/two times issue, She's likely to be calling twice this afternoon is rarely likely to be the "preferred" phrasing. On basic KISS principles, it would nearly always be She's likely to call twice this afternoon. Why complicate things for the sake of it?

I just want to know if it correct and accepable. That's it. When it comes to the past for instance " I have been playing 3 times this week" is wrong but I'm not sure about the future?

"I [will] have been playing 3 times this week" isn't "wrong" in the sense of being syntactically invalid. But it's ugly, awkward, and would almost never be the preferred phrasing in any context. When in doubt, use the simplest verb form that seems credible to you, not the most complex alternative.

I provided 4 examples. Can you comment all of them, please?

The verbs are all fine. They all mean different things, so it's pointless asking which is "best". Except that if you don't now why you're using the continuous in #4, it's virtually certain you shouldn't use it. And all 4 examples are poor quality English because of "two times", as has been repeatedly pointed out.
